# MVC View foreach list with tag-it (SO style tagging)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, tag-it

I am populating a table in my MVC View with some check boxes and I was looking to use [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) to get the same effect as SO.

Just wondering if there is anyone out there that would know how to incorporate my foreach method with tag-it so that when a tag is typed it first populates with whatever comes from my list and second makes it "selected" if its a chosen typed out field.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit();
    });
</script>

<ul id="myTags">
    <!-- Existing list items will be pre-added to the tags -->
    <li>Tag1</li>
    <li>Tag2</li>
</ul>
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <table>
            <tr>
                @{
                    int cnt = 0;
                    List<MyBlogger.Models.Tag> tag = ViewBag.Tags;
                    foreach (var tags in tag)
                    {
                        if (cnt++ % 3 == 0)
                    {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                        }
                        @:<td>
                             <input type="checkbox"
                                    name="selectedTags"
                                    value="@tags.Id"
                                    @(Html.Raw(tags.Assigned? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")) />
                                    @tags.Id @:  @tags.Name
                        @:</td>
                     }
                  @:</tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You really should use a proper ViewModel to get that logic out of the view.

Comment: Why did you delete your last question? I was drafting an answer! You seem to have a habit of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myTags").tagit({
            availableTags: @ViewBag.AllTags
        });
    });
</script>

<ul id="myTags">
    @foreach (var tag in (ViewBag.SelectedTags as List<MyBlogger.Models.Tag>))
    {
           <li>@tag.Name</li>
    }
</ul>
```

In your controller:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
ViewBag.AllTags = serializer.Serialize(context.Tags.ToArray());
ViewBag.SelectedTags = context.Tags.Where(w => w.Selected).ToList();
```

Assuming you are using EF's context and that you have some way to populate a list of all tags as well as tags that should be selected.